# Was Jacob's dream an answer to prayer? Genesis 35:3

Tags: genesis, jacob

How can Jacob's claim that God answered him (Gen 35:3) when there is no record of Jacob petitioning or praying to God in Genesis 28?

> Genesis 35:3 "Then come, let us go up to Bethel, where I will build an
> altar to God, **who answered me in the day of my distress** and who has
> been with me wherever I have gone.”

Jacob's dream in Genesis 28:10-15 is usually taught or explained as if God is here initiating everything without any prior interest on behalf of Jacob however Jacob's later description of this event as a response or answer from God seems to suggest the opposite. Wenham in his Genesis commentary makes the following remark about this but I am not sure what he is implying"

> Note how the ptcp (“answered“)
> in the relative clause is continued by finite verb (“has been“) (GKC,
> 116o,x; WOC, 561, 631).

Wenham, Gordon John. Genesis 16-50, Volume 2 (Word Biblical Commentary) (p. 320). Zondervan Academic. Kindle Edition.

Answer (score 1):

There are two matters here that should be addressed separately.

**1. To what incident does Gen 35:3 refer?**

Jacob refers to some incident in which God appeared to him and answered him in his distress.  I think there can be little doubt that Jacob is referring to the ladder/stairway to heaven incident in Gen 28:10-22 because:

- In Gen 35:1 - he is told to return to Bethel where the vision was received
- In the same verse Jacob says that this was the time when he fled in fear from his brother Esau

**2. Did God appear in answer to Jacob's plea?**

The Genesis record is necessarily incomplete - we do not have a record of every conversation and every incident affecting the lives of the characters.  Therefore, the fact that we have no record of a prayer from Jacob requesting divine help, is no evidence that such did not occur.

Therefore, assuming the record in Gen 35:1-5 is accurate (I see no reason to doubt it) we have a reference to such a plea for diving help from Jacob, as stated by the record:

> Gen 35:3, God, who answered me in my day of distress

Comment: what do you make of Wenham's comment? Any guess what was he trying to imply?

Comment: @Derek - all I can make of this remark is a fancy grammarians way of saying what we mortals simply read in the translation.  That is, God was with him in response to Jacob's plea for help.

Answer (score 0):

In Hebrew, the word "answer" can sometimes refer to fulfilling a prayer. Thus, this event is referring to when G-d answered Jacob when he made his prayer in Genesis 32:12 which says "Please deliver me from the hand of my brother Esau, because I am scared that he will strike down my camp, mothers and children alike" (Genesis 32:12). Then, finally when Jacob reaches Esau, "And Esau ran to greet him, he hugged him falling on his neck, he kissed him, and they wept" (Genesis 33:4). Thus we see that Jacob understands this incident as G-d delivering him, as he feared that Esau would kill him, and G-d turned Esau killing him into Esau hugging and kissing him.

Comment: How exactly did Jacob "flee" from Esau in Chapter 32? The same word used here (35:1) is the same word used to describe his flight from Esau in Genesis 27:43.

Comment: The answering does not have to be the same event. They are discussing different events.

Comment: I don't understand, how can we know for certain that Gen 35:1-3 are referring to different events?

Comment: What I am saying is that they don't have to be referring to the same event. I could of course be wrong, but there is no reason to require them to be the same event.

Answer (score 0):

Jacob's claim that God answered him (Gen 35:3) could reasonably refer to the actual oath Jacob made (interpreted as a prayer-oath) when naming the place Beth-El. It,  however, is unreasonable to interpret the Vision of God as a response to a prayer since Gen. 28:16 states

> Jacob awoke from his sleep and said: "Indeed, God's presence is in
> this place and I didn't know it.

Jacob was surprised. This clearly shows that God did initiate the Vision. However verses 18-22 read as follows:

> Jacob awoke in the morning; he took the stone on which he rested his
> head and made it a monument; he poured oil on its head. And Jacob
> named the place Beth-El (literally, House of God), even though
> originally its name was Luz.

And Jacob vowed a vow as follows:

> If God will be with me, watch me on the path I am going, give me food
> to eat and garb to wear, I return safely to my father's household, and
> God will be my Lord, then this stone which I have made a monument will
> be a House of God, and of all You give me I will give a tenth to you.

I think it plausible to regard this as a coupled prayer-vow. Jacob is praying for safety, food, garb, and a peaceful return and in exchange for God being Jacob's Lord (constantly watching and providing) Jacob vows to make Beth-El a house of God and to give tithes.

It is pretty explicit  that Jacob alludes to this vow-prayer in Gen 31:7-13.

> And your father (speaking to his wife) belittled me and changed my
> wages 10 fold but God did not allow him to harm me.....God appeared to
> me in visions [when Laban attempted to change wages]...God say "I am
> the Almighty of Beth-El where you anointed a monument and made a vow.

As to the grammar of "answer" I would note that the present conjugation is used

> To the God who answers me on the day of my problems and     who was with
> me on the path I went.

Building on Wenham's observations, we see two verbs in this sentence. Answer is conjugated in the present while "who was with me" is conjugated in the past.

I think it reasonable (and consistent with the English translation ) to interpret this as a habitual present, "God who answers me whenever I have a problem." There is no standard way to indicate the habitual present in biblical Hebrew and it can be indicated by a future, past, or present conjugation so this is a reasonable approach